# Can't ProcessData on RSS Reader

Tags: .net, rss

I am trying to build a simple RSS reader in C#.NET and following the example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410776%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

I am stuck on the line ProcessData pd = content.ReadContent();

Where do I import ProcessData from? What components do I need to use to access this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is no magical import for this class. Essentially it is object from business domain, that can be serialized to xml. So you can create your own ProcessData class with properties matching to items of xml feed you're reading. Its using DataContractSerializer, so be sure to decorate your ProcessData class with [DataContract] and properties with [DataMember] attributes.